# SP 2007 error: Cannot move <file name> : Cannot read from the source file or disk (cut and paste in explorer view)

Tags: 2007, document-library, explorer-view

SharePoint 2007

I am opening two document libraries in explorer view and if I try to Cut a document from one library and paste it into another library we are getting an error.

Error Message:
Error moving file or folder
Cannot move  : Cannot read from the source file or disk.

I am able to copy and paste from explorer view without incident but, if I try to cut and paste we keep getting this error message.  currently, we are just copy and pasting documents and going back to the original document library and deleting them.

Is there a way to enable the ability to cut and paste between document libraries from explorer view?  Having to keep going back to delete the file after it was copied to it's new location doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

Explorer view does support cut, copy, and paste operations.

It is a bit of a complex beast to deal with and track down issues.  I would start by loading up Fiddler and inspecting the traffic to see where the breakdown is.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Also review this whitepaper on explorer view:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9981

Comment: Thanks for sending the link for troubleshooting the Explorer View.  It appears the issue was easily resolved.  I resolved this issue by going into the security settings in IE and enabling the IFRAME from the Local Intranet security settings as described below.  If anyone is experiencing the same problem, I would recommend trying this:

Comment: 1.Open Internet Explorer. 2.On the menu bar, click Tools and then click Internet Options. 3.Click the Security tab 4.Click the appropriate zone(Local Intranet). 5.Click Custom Level. 6.Select Enable for item labeled Launching programs and files in an IFRAME 7.Click OK. 8.Click Yes when prompted to change the settings, 9.Click OK. 10.Restart Internet Explorer. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction in resolving this issue. Much appreciated, Robert